# LWJGL move camera forward (in the direction its facing)

Tags: java, camera, lwjgl

My problem is that when I press W and look like 45° to the right, I'm not moving into that direction, but mainly forward (I'm moving very slightly to the right). I looked up different resources which told me to do it the way I did. My current move code in my camera class looks as following:

```
[...]
        var offsetZ = 0.0f
        if(KeyboardInputHandler.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_W)) offsetZ -= speed
        if(KeyboardInputHandler.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_S)) offsetZ += speed

        if(offsetZ != 0.0f) {
            position.x += -offsetZ * sin(degreeToRadiant(rotY))
            position.z += offsetZ * cos(degreeToRadiant(rotY))
        }

        var offsetX = 0.0f
        if(KeyboardInputHandler.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_A)) offsetX -= speed
        if(KeyboardInputHandler.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_D)) offsetX += speed

        if(offsetX != 0.0f) {
            position.x += -offsetX * sin(degreeToRadiant(rotY - 90.0f))
            position.z += offsetX * cos(degreeToRadiant(rotY - 90.0f))
        }
[...]
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Very stupid mistake from me: The rotY variable was already in radiant, so I basically put a radiant in a degreeToRadiant method, thats why it wasnt moving sideways.